# Filtering logs for entries greater than a specific value

Tags: web3js, events, logs, filters

I know that you can filter logs in web3 by topic using:

```
web3.eth.filter({
   topics: ["0x00..."]
}).watch(console.log)
```

Is it possible to filter for a topic value greater than a given value?

Answer (score 1):

`web3.eth.filter` converts the topics to hex values and passes them to the JSON RPC call `eth_newFilter`.

From the specification for the JSON RPC call [eth_newFilter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter):

> Topics are order-dependent. Each topic can also be an array of DATA
>   with "or" options.

Looks like it only checks if the topics in the log match with the topic or set of topics you pass it.

You would have to do any further filtering in your callback function.